# Lua script how to invoke/call zenity or notify-send?

Tags: lua, zenity, notify-send

I'm a beginner in lua
OS: Manjaro XFCE

If I run from terminal desktop notification with notify-send or zenity it works.
for instance:

```
notify-send -t 4000 'Displays for 4 secs' "understood!!"
```

However, I can make it work from a lua script.

```lua
#!/usr/bin/lua

print ("basic test")

notify-send -t 4000 'Displays for 4 secs' "understood!!"
```

How to fix this, I tried several ways, incl os.execute(), but without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```lua
os.execute("notify-send -t 4000 'Displays for 4 secs' 'understood!!'")
```